# how to fix error 1009 in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

hi i have been trying to fix this by searching the net  for hours and have had no luck so all help is appreciated (it happened when i put the snow in)
Thanks in Advance

Here's my code:

```
Quit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func22);

function func22(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
    myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener3);
    myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener4);
}

Help.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func33);

function func33(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(23);
    myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener3);
    myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener4);
}

var myTimer3:Timer = new Timer(2000,0);
myTimer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener3);
function timerListener3(e:TimerEvent):void {
Hungry_bar.scaleX-=0.05;
if(Hungry_bar.scaleX<=0.05){
        gotoAndStop(12)
        myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
        myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    }
}
myTimer3.start();

var myTimer4:Timer = new Timer(3000,0);
myTimer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener4);
function timerListener4(e:TimerEvent):void {
Fun_bar.scaleX-=0.05;
if(Fun_bar.scaleX<=0.05){
        gotoAndStop(13)
        myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener3);
        myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener4);
    }
}
myTimer4.start();

Feed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,feed2)
function feed2(e:MouseEvent){
Hungry_bar.scaleX+=0.05
if(Hungry_bar.scaleX>=1.5){
    gotoAndStop(14)
    myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener3);
    myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener4);
    }
}

Fun.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,happy2)
function happy2(e:MouseEvent){
    Fun_bar.scaleX+=0.05
    if(Fun_bar.scaleX>=1.5){
    gotoAndStop(15)
    myTimer3.stop(); myTimer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    myTimer4.stop(); myTimer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    }
}

//snow

var snowflakes:Array = new Array();
var snowflakeProps:Dictionary= new Dictionary(true);
var max_snowsize:Number = .04;
// pixels
var snowflakesCnt:Number = 150;
var oheight:Number;
var owidth:Number;
init();
function init():void {

    owidth = width;
    oheight = height;
    // quantity
    for (var i:int=0; i<snowflakesCnt; i++) {

    var t:MovieClip = new SnowFlake();//
    t.name = "snowflake"+i;

    t.alpha = .2+Math.random()*.6;
    t.x = -(owidth/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*owidth);
    t.y = -(oheight/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*oheight);
    t.scaleX = t.scaleY=.5+Math.random()*(max_snowsize*10);
    var o:Object = new Object();
    o.k = 1+Math.random()*2;
    o.wind = -1.5+Math.random()*(1.4*3);

    snowflakeProps[t] = o;

    addChild(t);
    snowflakes.push(t);
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, snowFlakeMover);
}
function shakeUp():void{
for (var i:int=0; i<snowflakes.length; i++) {
    var t:MovieClip = snowflakes[i] as MovieClip;
    t.x = -(owidth/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*owidth);
    t.y = -(oheight/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*oheight);
    }
}
function snowFlakeMover(evt:Event):void {
var dO:MovieClip;
var o :Object;
if(visible && parent.visible){
for (var i:int = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
    dO = snowflakes[i] as MovieClip;
    o = snowflakeProps[dO];
    dO.y += o.k;
    dO.x += o.wind;
    if (dO.y>oheight+10) {

        dO.y = -20;

    }
    if (dO.x>owidth+20) {

        dO.x = -(owidth/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*owidth);
        dO.y = -20;

    } else if (dO.x<-20) {

        dO.x= -(owidth/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*owidth);
        dO.y = -20;
    }

}
}
}
```

and here is the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at petgamewithweather_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[petgamewithweather_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:9]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at petgamewithweather_fla::MainTimeline/func22()[petgamewithweather_fla.MainTimeline::frame16:5]
```

Comment: You have code on frame 2, line 9 which is throwing this error. What code is that?

Comment: stop();
Start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func1);

function func1(event: MouseEvent): void 
{
 gotoAndStop(28)
}

Help.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func7);                                                                                                                                                          function func7(event: MouseEvent): void 
{
 gotoAndStop(3)
}

Comment: Only one of those lines is line 9, which one is it?

Comment: Help.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func7);

Comment: Then `Help` is null.

Comment: but i have an instance name

Comment: Then the instance is not on frame 2.

Comment: you realize that the error tells you where the error is (frame 2) and what line (9) and what's the problem ()a null instance and you come here asking question about this. All that anybody can tell you is "the error is on frame 2 line 9 and you have a null instance there" which is what the error already told you.